# Vue 2 Single File Component doesn't work with runtime only build

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

i try to use single file components with the runtime only build. When i use the full vue build everythings works as expected. I thought single file components are pre-compiled. Why aren't the components rendered when i use the runtime only build.

Here is my setup:

webpack.config.js :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = {
entry: "./src/main.ts",
output: { filename: "dist/bundle.js" },
resolve: {
    alias: {
        vue: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js'
            //vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    }
},
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                esModule: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

main.ts

```
import Vue from "vue";
import MyFirstComponent from "./MyFirstComponent.vue";
import MySecondComponent from "./MySecondComponent.vue"

Vue.component("my-first-component", MyFirstComponent);
Vue.component("my-second-component", MySecondComponent);

new Vue({
    el: "#app"
});
```

MyFirstComponent.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    This is the first component!
</div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component
export default class MyFirstComponent extends Vue {
    public mounted() {
        console.log("mounted!");
    }
}
</script>
```

The "MySecondComponent" is similar to the first.

Can anyone explain why this isn't working with the runtime only build?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's on the official documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Terms

> **Compiler**: code that is responsible for compiling template strings into JavaScript render functions.
>
> **Runtime**: code that is responsible for creating Vue instances, rendering and patching virtual DOM, etc. Basically everything minus the compiler.

When using the runtime-only build, you exclude the compiler that's essential to compile your template into JS render functions. In other words, the view (the HTML inside your `<template></template>`) of your component will never get compiled, and will never appear in the DOM, with a runtime-only build.